# Swift including JustHTTP/Just build fail

Tags: ios, swift

I am using XCode6.4 and I imported JustHTTP/Just (https://github.com/justhttp/Just) library using Carthage.

Import worked fine and here is a screenshot of my xcodeproj file
[image]

But on this line:

```
import Just
```

I am getting this error

```
Module file was created by a newer version of the compiler
...../Carthage/Build/iOS/Just.framework/Modules/Just.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

Can someone advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default branch (v0.3) is on Swift 2. So I had to either switch to Xcode 7 or use github "JustHTTP/Just" ~> v0.1 in my Cartfile.